# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE userid

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE userid

```
public static User updateAccountbyUser(User updateinfo){
        System.out.println(updateinfo.getName() +"=custName");
        try {
            getConnection();
            String updateSQL =  "UPDATE dchan.user SET " +
                " dchan.user.name = ? WHERE userid"+updateinfo.getId() ;
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(updateSQL);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, updateinfo.getName());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate(updateSQL);
            return updateinfo;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        prepareDisconnect();
        return null;
    } //ends updateUserAccount
```

Comment: `WHERE userid"+updateinfo.getId()`... think about that 3 seconds.

Comment: Unless `updateinfo.getId()` contains an `=` character, you're missing an `=` character.

Comment: I have rolled back to the original question - if you have a new question, ask a new question, don't edit this one.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an `=`.

```
" dchan.user.name = ? WHERE userid = "+updateinfo.getId() ;
```

This said, this defies the point of using a prepared statement. What you really want is:

```
String updateSQL =  "UPDATE dchan.user SET " +
                    "dchan.user.name = ? WHERE userid = ?";
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(updateSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, updateinfo.getName());
preparedStatement.setString(2, updateinfo.getId());
```

Comment: still having issues after change

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE userid = ?' at line 1

Comment: @user3621683 Are you trying to execute this outside of a prepared statement? The `?` is a place-holder in a prepared statement, but will be a syntax error elsewhere. Please run the actual code from your question, but updated.

Comment: userid will be a current user logged in called "currentuser" which is an object so i will do something like this jdbcclass.updateAccountuser(updateduser()) != null {sop "your account is update).  static user updateduser(){ if you want to change your name then it will prompt to change your name and then it will call currentuser.setName(name); return currentuser}//ends updateuser

Comment: @user3621683 I'm not sure what you are trying to tell me here, or how it relates to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
String updateSQL =  "UPDATE dchan.user SET " +
  " dchan.user.name = ? WHERE userid"+updateinfo.getId() ;
```

you probably want:

```
String updateSQL =  "UPDATE dchan.user SET " +
  " dchan.user.name = ? WHERE userid =" + updateinfo.getId() ;
```

(missing equal sign after *userid*).

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE userid = ?' at line 1